# How do I capture the Screensaver Event?

Tags: c#, events, interop

I'm trying to capture a Screensaver event, however when I run my application it throws the following exception;

Unable to find an entry point named 'SystemParametersinfo' in DLL 'user32.dll'.

this is my code so far, any and all help would be greatly appreciated =D

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using NLog;
using Topshelf;
using OsWatch;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;


namespace NotifyIcon
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            SystemEvents.SessionSwitch += SystemEvents_SessionSwitch;

        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public static extern int SystemParametersinfo(int uAction, int uParam, ref int ipvParam, int fuWinini);

        const int SPI_GETSCREENSAVERRUNNING = 114;
        static int screenSaverRunning = -1;
        int ok = SystemParametersinfo(SPI_GETSCREENSAVERRUNNING, 0, ref screenSaverRunning, 0);

        private void ScreenSaver()
        {
            if (ok == 0)
            {
                Logger.Trace("SCREENSAVER OFF");
            }

            if (screenSaverRunning != 0)
            {
                Logger.Trace("SCREENSAVER ON");

            }
        }
```

Comment: You forgot the caps in info... It needs to be `SystemParametersInfo`.

Comment: Indeed it does lol! sorry to have posted a question with such an obvious answer =P thanks!

Comment: Why don't you post the working version as an answer? Ma help others.

Comment: Because I no longer have access to this code :(